# Raspberry Pi 3 Ubuntu 16.04 Server upgrade error

Tags: pi-3, apt, ubuntu, update, u-boot

So last week I bought the **Raspberry Pi 3 model B** with the complete Canakit. I installed **Ubuntu 16.04 server standard** image on the micro sd card with my **Windows** computer.

I used **SF Formatter** to format my micro sd card with the Format Size Adjustement option On. 
I also used **Win32DiskImager** to write my image on the micro sd card.

Here's the Ubuntu image file that I used:
http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/ubuntu-rpi3/ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz

The first boot went well. I used that command to upgrade my Raspberry PI:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After that, I rebooted my Raspberry PI and **it always got stuck on the u-boot screen**. It's like it can't find the OS.

I can add the error code tonight when I get home. I've tried it multiple time and it didn't worked everytime. I also have a Macbook Pro, so if it changed anything I can try to format and write on my micro sd card with it.

**Update 1:**
Here's the error message that I am talking about. It occur when I boot my Raspberry Pi 3 with my Ubuntu Server 16.04 standard upgraded.
[image: u-boot error]

Comment: I got exactly the same problem, and I used apt-get upgrade (not dist-upgrade)

Comment: Same situation here, even running only "**apt-get upgrade**" breaks your install the next reboot!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
In my case, the following instructions fixed the problem:

- install, boot, sudo apt upgrade, reboot
- u-boot error
- plug microSD to PC
- edit 'device_tree_address' on config.txt

```
    # original
    device_tree_address=0x100
    device_tree_end=0x8000

    # modified
    device_tree_address=0x02008000
```

- insert microSD to Pi3 again
- boot

References: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi2/+bug/1652270
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi2/+bug/1652270/comments/34

Comment: In my case, I had to comment out device_tree_end=0x8000 to get it working, this is also mentioned in your references.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is attempting to run `dist-upgrade`.

AFAIK your system is now broken, and your only option is to restore from backup.

`dist-upgrade` runs the standard Ubuntu upgrade, which tries to install standard boot sector etc.

There does **NOT** appear to be a version of `dist-upgrade` for MATE ARM for the Pi.

---

> Edit The latest update to

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Kernel: Linux 4.4.38-v7+
```

> Now includes raspberrypi-bootloader (1.20161215-1~xenial1.0)
>
> Ubuntu MATE seems to have joined Arch and Raspbian in updating kernel (to the latest Foundation supported version) with `sudo apt upgrade`. This was before the official announcement of the [update](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-16-04-2-for-raspberry-pi-2-and-raspberry-pi-3-is-out/11566)

(I have not tried what `dist-upgrade` does on the latest, but there seems to be no need.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should I use the apt-get upgrade or just let it as the image version?

Comment: @FrankNoel you can use `upgrade` to update software, but this will not update firmware, and you certainly can't update to 16.10.

Comment: Would the rpi-update and the upgrade command work? Or should I stay at this version?

Comment: `rpi-update` will upgrade firmware (with the usual caveats about installing possible testing versions). The only way to upgrade to a newer release e.g. 16.10 to to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

i had nearly the same problem as the author.

I have a PI3 here with ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img installed. 
Right after doing the update and upgrade procedure (not dist-upgrade) my system was not able to boot up anymore. First i tried to modify my config.txt ( device_tree_address=0x02008000 ) as mentioned earlier by someone else. Unfortunately this did not fix the problem.

So i decided to try something else: I copied over all the files i found in the folder "system-boot" inside my original ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img file to the sdcard by overwriting existing files.
After that my PI was able to boot into xenial again.

Than i tried to use dist-upgrade. After i did reboot, again my system didn't work. Again I first tried the fix that was mentioned before ( device_tree_address=0x02008000 ) and it worked for me. 
Anyway I also retried the procedure i did before ( overwriting the files in "system-boot" ) and again, it worked.

I am defenitely no computerexpert. So i dont know if this might effect my system with bad behavior in future. But for the moment, i use it as workaround.

EDIT:
After some testing i found out that i was unable to detect my wifi-device after doing the dist-upgrade-procedure. 
To fix this, i did a backup of the file /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt before upgrading. After reboot I copied the file back to it's place (somehow it gets deleted by the system during the upgrade-procedure), did another reboot and now the wifi is back online.

Answer (score 0):

Simple = be attention on the information

Edit file...

```
# original
device_tree_address=0x100
device_tree_end=0x8000

# modified
device_tree_address=0x02008000
#device_tree_end=0x8000
```

WORKED PERFECTLY !!!