# Raspberry Pi 3 dosn't boot after apt upgrade

Tags: ubuntu

I've just bought a Raspberry Pi 3.

I've downloaded the Ubuntu Server image for Raspberry Pi 3 from the [official site](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/). I formatted the SD with SDFormatter and wrote the image to the SD with Win32DiskImager.

It initializes OK the first time, I changed the password and then I did an update and rebooted the system with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo reboot`.

After that, the boot process stops at some point with the message:

```
Raspberry Retry count exceeded; trying again
UBOOT>
```

I'd really appreciate some help!

Comment: Looks like the upgrade process is damaging your boot area. The hard part is to find what. Do the upgrade process is small steps, booting after each one, during upgrade pick from the list just a few packages and reboot. I will select kernel related upgrades first. Also, make sure you have enough space available.

Comment: I didn't reboot in the first boot (just after asking for password change). I do straight for the apt update and upgrade. Can this be the problem !?

Comment: Possible the same problem: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61342/raspberry-pi-3-ubuntu-16-04-server-upgrade-error

Comment: Well, my solution 'till now was migrate to Mate and make it headless...