# Ubuntu server on raspi 3, poweroff.. how to reboot?

Tags: power, ubuntu

I grabbed an iso of ubuntu 16 for raspi 3 from here: https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/

I ssh'd in with ubuntu, set a password.

Ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

All good so far.

Then I ran `poweroff`, great, the raspi appears to powerdown... leave it a bit but the leds are still on and red.

Leave for a total of about 4 mins.. led is still solid red.

Disconnect the lan and usb, leave for a bit.

Plug the lan and then the power source back in, but this time the little guys isn't booting up, the led is just solid red with nothing else.

This post is talking about a powerswitch: [How do I turn on my Raspberry Pi after shutdown?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5489/how-do-i-turn-on-my-raspberry-pi-after-shutdown)

Is there a way to boot a raspi without buying this powerswitch? It's Easter and the shops aint open till Tuesday.. :/

**UPDATE**
Here is a snapshot of the little pi trying to boot up while connected to a screen.[image]

If you can make out the image the first main error seems to be

> No FDT memory address configured. Please configure the FDT address via
>   "fdt add " command.

Then following with

> ERROR: Did not find a cmbline Flattened Device Tree

:( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi2/+bug/1652270

UPDATE
After some further reading it seams the iso i used (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) is not supported by cononical. I am now trying the https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3 version.

Comment: That powerswitch would only save you the replugging of the USB cable.
You seem to have another problem with your system not booting at all

Comment: You don't say exactly which dist you used, but MATE should work. Unfortunately Pi crashes on upgrade are not uncommon - just bad luck. I always make a backup first. I suggest you try again.

Comment: I choose this dist:  "Ubuntu Classic Server 16.04  Raspberry Pi 3 (216MB)"

I think i will have to get a screen hooked up and see what is happening during boot.

Comment: The latest link is `Snappy Ubuntu Core` which is probably **NOT** what you want (unless you are developing snap-ins). The `MATE` download from https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/ works without any problems. I have used earlier versions of `Ubuntu Classic Server`, which are OK **if** you want a server. **NONE** of the distributions for Pi (except Snappy) are supported by Canonical, they are user ports.

Answer (score 0):

Boot issue seems to be the same problem:　[Raspberry Pi 3 Ubuntu 16.04 Server upgrade error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61342/raspberry-pi-3-ubuntu-16-04-server-upgrade-error/62384)

How about editing 'config.txt' on MicroSD like my answer? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/62384/62515

```
# original
device_tree_address=0x100
device_tree_end=0x8000

# modified
device_tree_address=0x02008000
```